# Sort JavaScript array of Objects based on one of the object's properties

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of objects, each of which has a property `name`, a string. I'd like to sort the array by this property. I'd like them sorted in the following way..

```
`ABC`
`abc`
`BAC`
`bac`
etc...
```

How would I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Isn't this `array.sort()` ? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Raynos: No it doesn't. You need to compare the `name` property of each object, which `sort()` will not do without a custom function.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are 2 basic ways:

```
var arr = [{name:"ABC"},{name:"BAC"},{name:"abc"},{name:"bac"}];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
  var alc = a.name.toLowerCase(), blc = b.name.toLowerCase();
  return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
 });
```

or

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
 });
```

Be aware that the 2nd version ignore diacritics, so `a` and `à` will be sorted as the same letter.

Now the problem with both these ways is that they will not sort uppercase `ABC` before lowercase `abc`, since it will treat them as the same.

To fix that, you will have to do it like this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  var alc = a.name.toLowerCase(), blc = b.name.toLowerCase();
  return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Again here you could choose to use `localeCompare` instead if you don't want diacritics to affect the sorting like this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  var lccomp = a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
  return lccomp ? lccomp : a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0;
});
```

You can read more about sort here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Doesn't work for Romanian diacritics... :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can pass-in a [sort function reference to Array.sort](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml).

Comment: Together with the accepted answer, this helped me solve the issue. I think it should be a part of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom sorting function to the `sort()` method of an array. The following will do the trick and take your requirements about capitalization into account.

```
objects.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    var n1 = o1.name, n2 = o2.name, ni1 = n1.toLowerCase(), ni2 = n2.toLowerCase();
    return ni1 === ni2 ? (n1 === n2 ? 0 : n1 > n2 ? 1 : -1) : (ni1 > ni2 ? 1 : -1);
});
```

Comment: isn't that the same as `array.sort()` I think you just passed in the default sorting function directly.

Comment: @Raynos: No, my function compares the `name` property of two objects. I have updated it now to account for the order the OP wanted regarding capitalization.

Comment: I completely overlooked that you have to compare names not object references. Such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified from *[Sorting an array of objects](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml)*,

```
yourobject.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name, nameB = b.name
    if (nameA < nameB) //Sort string ascending.
        return -1
    if (nameA > nameB)
        return 1
    return 0 //Default return value (no sorting).
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
objects.sort(function(c, d) {
    return (
        c['name'].toLowerCase() > d['name'].toLowerCase() || 
            c['name'] > d['name']
    ) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

see there http://jsfiddle.net/p8Gny/1/

Comment: This is not the right way to use the sort funciton which needs a return range of 1,0,-1 and not true,false like yours return. Read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Martin Jespersen Thank you for correcting me.