# How to search JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"LastName":"Micheal","FirstName":"John"}
```

I have a Json data. When i type my last name or a single character in my text field, it should search this value... and get me the response.

My json data is stored in a file and i am able to read it and get into in a variable too... from there... i am not able too

Answer (score 1):

it's called autocomplete, you need a database for looking the data retrieve, and the js/jquery methods for comparison and searching into the data

Comment: My json data is stored in a file and i am able to read it and get into in a variable too... from there... i am not able too

Comment: I am able to fetch the data, but not able to sort the results according to lastname... if you can show me an example it would be great... thanks

Comment: @theJava: please always show what you have so far, so we can make suggestions. Not to offend you, but we're not here to write your code.

Comment: @theJava: BTW, if you want to sort results in an array containing objects like you showed in your question, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421253/sort-javascript-array-of-objects/5421390#5421390