# How do I perform a merge sort based on the property of an object (rather than an Array)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, sorting

### Background

Using JavaScript, I need to sort a large JSON object based on a given property of that object.  **I am assuming that a merge sort is the fastest approach**.  If this is not the fastest approach, please tell me what is.  There are myriad examples online of a merge sort against an array, but very little with objects.  Here is a sample object:

```
fruitForSale = {
     1: {"type":"orange","UnitPrice":0.20},
     2: {"type":"banana","UnitPrice":0.30},
     3: {"type":"pear","UnitPrice":0.10},
     4: {"type":"apple","UnitPrice":0.50},
     5: {"type":"peach","UnitPrice":0.70}
}
```

### Question

Using a merge sort (or faster algorithm), how would I sort the `fruitForSale` object so that I end up with an object sorted by 'type':

```
   fruitForSale = {
                     4: {"type":"apple","UnitPrice":0.50},
                     2: {"type":"banana","UnitPrice":0.30},
                     1: {"type":"orange","UnitPrice":0.20},
                     5: {"type":"peach","UnitPrice":0.70},
                     3: {"type":"pear","UnitPrice":0.10}                  
                   }
```

NOTE: The original `keys` (1,2,3,4 & 5) would need to stay assigned to their respective object, so a key of `1` should always match with `{"type":"orange","UnitPrice":0.20}` and a key of `2` will always match with `{"type":"banana","UnitPrice":0.30}` and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot sort object properties. You can create an array of keys or just create an array of objects. Then have a look at [Sort JavaScript array of Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421253/sort-javascript-array-of-objects) or [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+array+of+objects+by+field&submit=search).

Comment: in addition, Objects have no order (although they seem to have). This looks like an array to me, why complicate things by using objects instead?

Comment: @Felix: Couldn't he do 

    `fruitForSale.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.type - b.type;
    })`

Comment: @playeren: No, objects don't provide a `sort` method.

Comment: @David--I need the keys because I have used them to establish a relationship with another JSON object.  Thanks.

Comment: You could do `fruitForSale.length = 5; [].sort.call(fruitForSale, function(a,b){ return a.type > b.type });` ... but it would destroy your keys. As others mentioned, object properties aren't ordered, so "sorting" them really makes no sense unless you mean re-numbering numeric keys.

Comment: Why the down-vote after the question was asked and answered??  Drive-by??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort the keys on the object, but you can keep your own array of sorted keys.

```
var fruitForSale = {
     1: {"type":"orange","UnitPrice":0.20},
     2: {"type":"banana","UnitPrice":0.30},
     3: {"type":"pear","UnitPrice":0.10},
     4: {"type":"apple","UnitPrice":0.50},
     5: {"type":"peach","UnitPrice":0.70}
},

sortedKeys = Object.keys(fruitForSale).sort(function (i,j) {
    return fruitForSale[i]["type"] > fruitForSale[j]["type"];
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2hFt/ (Output displayed on the console)

Object.keys is not supported everywhere but you can polyfill if you need to easily. **See**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Oh, and if you are curious about the underlying implementation of sort see:

[Javascript Array.sort implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)