# Need to sort the Javascript array according to some logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

I have a array `myResponse.students[i]`

I calculate the Total marks for every student in the array through some logic and now i want to sort the array based on total marks which i calculate. How to do this using javascript?

Comment: Is this an array of numbers or an array of objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [Sort JavaScript array of Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421253/sort-javascript-array-of-objects).

Comment: @FelixKling Its array of Objects... To get the name i need to do this `myResponse.students[i].student.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume as your students is the array you want to sort

```
myResponse.students.sort(byMark)

function byMark(a, b){
     return b.mark - a.mark; // sort score desc
}
```

Comment: sort function will pick and object in array as a and b to compare. you can do anything in sort function to return your defind value. return value will tell compare function how to sort. return 0 = equal, return 1 or greater mean a is greater , return -1 or lower mean a is lower than b

Comment: Hi... I understood it. But in my case the Total marks are not in array... I calculate it outside...

Comment: can you show your total marks calculate function?
may be you want this `function byMark(a,b){ return cal(a) - cal(b); }`
if your calculate function calculate from your array object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myResponse.students.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return parseFloat(a.TotalMarks) - parseFloat(b.TotalMarks) ;
});
```

The signature of sort function is this

> array.sort([compareFunction])

Please go through the documentation to get a better idea of `compareFunction`

Link: [array.sort MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Hi Naveen.. What is `a` & `b` here?

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

You can pass your comparator function as parameter to the sort function.

This function takes two values to be compared from the array, and you need to provide logic for returning `0` or `1` or `-1` as following

```
var a = [...]; //your array
a.sort(compareFunction);

function compareFunction (a, b)
{
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```