# Sorting a array of objects based on the value of one of the properties of the objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort JavaScript array of Objects based on one of the object’s properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421253/sort-javascript-array-of-objects-based-on-one-of-the-objects-properties)

I have an object which has a property called z:

```
function building(z)
{
  this.z = z;
}
```

Let's say I create 3 instances of this object:

```
a = new building(5)
b = new building(2)
c = new building(8)
```

These instances are then placed into an array

```
buildings = []
buildings.push(a)
buildings.push(b)
buildings.push(c)
```

**The Question**

How would I sort this array **IN ASCENDING ORDER** based on the *z* property of the objects it contains? 
The end result after sorting should be:

```
before -> buildings = [a, b, c] 
sort - > buildings.sort(fu)
after -> buildings = [b, a, c]
```

Answer (score 5):

you can pass a compare-function to `.sort()`

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.z < b.z)
     return -1;
  if (a.z > b.z)
     return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

then use:

```
myarray.sort(compare)
```

here are some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I'm aware of this but the question I have is what would the compare function be? I'm new to using compare functions so would appreciate some help.