# How to sort Array by alpha of a specific key inside each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Example of my Array =

```
[{
    name: leon,
    id: 1
}, {
    name: laura
    id: 20003
}, {
    name: anne
    id: 45
}]
```

Currently in the UI, the array will look like:

- leon
- laura
- anne

How can one use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to sort the array by the `name` keys in alphabetical order?

Comment: You don't have to use lodash, you can just use the native [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Comment: if you want pure js way see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648076/sort-array-on-key-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.sortBy(myObjects, 'name');
```

Name is the sort key here

Comment: Thanks! This is way easier to read and understand than the normal JavaScript way

Comment: Btw I also just figured out that this works: `namesArray = _.orderBy(res, ['name'], ['asc', 'desc']);`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need lodash to do that...

Just do

```
var sortedNames = names.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p07c4oaa/

Or wrap that in a function like:

```
function sortBy(obj, key) {
  return obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
  });
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p07c4oaa/1/

Comment: @NinaScholz I used assignment because I have different variable names. But sure without is fine also.

Comment: Thanks! +1, the reason I was looking for a lodash solution, is because their API is so much easier to reason about quickly by other devs.

Comment: @LeonGaban no prob. Keep in mind that adding lodash to do such simple task might be overkill and slowing down your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proper callback.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'leon', id: 1}, { name: 'laura', id: 20003}, { name: 'anne', id: 45}];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of loadash but you can use simple [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort the json array of objects

```
var arry=[{
    name: 'leon',
    id: 1
}, {
    name: 'laura',
    id: 20003
}, {
    name: 'anne',
    id: 45
}]
var sorted = arry.sort(function(a,b){
return a.name > b.name ? 1:-1
})
// this part just for demo

sorted.forEach(function(item){
document.write('<pre>'+item.name+'</pre>')

})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yq9zenaz/5/)